# iOS 8 causes strange back box on initial view

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8

An existing application that has been upgraded from iOS 5->6->7 and now 8. On the initial view shown I have a strange black rectangle appearing, does anyone know why? I have included screen shots from iOS 7 and iOS 8.

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
loginWindow = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
loginWindow.delegate = self;
self.window.rootViewController = loginWindow;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

[image: iOS 8]
[image: iOS 7]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't look like a black box appearing...  it looks like your background image has been resized & repositioned.

Actually, there's a slither of black along the lefthand edge aswell, as though you have two background images, and one of them has resized.

Does your screen have AutoLayout turned on ?

If so, have you set constraints on this image, fixing it to the left & right hand edges of your display ?

And has this issue just happened since upgrading to XCode 6.x ?

And finally, in your Storyboard, if you click on your background image, select the Attributes Inspector, what setting do you have for "Mode" ?  Is is "Aspect fit", "Scale to fill", etc ?

Comment: Thanks, doh! that makes sense. It is not an Xcode 6 issue, more-so iOS 8, it does not misbehave in iOS 7.  There are no story boards, due to age of project it is XIB files. I have changed the properties and it looks fine now.